# useState and useEffect in terms of Firestore function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a messenger/chat part for my application. For Google Firebase version 9 modular, the website gives this code as an example for getting data from firestore:

```
import { getFirestore, collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

const q = query(collection(db, "cities"), where("capital", "==", true));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

I am not sure how to go about using this code with a useState/useEffect within a function. Unless I don't need to use these for grabbing messages, createdAt, profilePicture, etc. and displaying them on screen? I've encountered async problems with await and unreserved word for await when trying to modify my code using this new syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to run these queries in `useEffect()`, try this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const getDocuments = async () => {
    const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

    const q = query(collection(db, "cities"), where("capital", "==", true));

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
  }

  getDocuments()
}, [])
```